# Windriver VxWorks Simulator Self modifying code

Tags: memory, kernel, simulator, vxworks, mmu

Good morning.

I have a program that is Self-Modifying-Code.

Really, it build the binaries, which then are changed by `ELFPatch` and changes some function's prologues.

I am working with **Windriver WorkBench 3.3 & VxWorks 6.9 Update3**.

I created a standard simulator (PENTIUM),
when i run my code on the simulator:

```
void replace_prolog(void* func_ptr) {
    char* p = (char*)func_ptr;
    for (int i=0; i < PROLOGUE_SIZE; ++i)
        p[i]=m_prologue[i]; // << prologue is a member array. 
    ...
}
```

Let's call the Real Prologue : Original Prologue;
The Changed Prologue : Changed Prologue;
The One that is placed at Run-Time : Replacement Prologue;

I get an Exception (signal 11 - Segmentation Fault).
!! I realized it is VxWorks's `.text` Segment Protection.

So, I created a `SimPC based VIP` to be my simulator BSP, and **excluded `INCLUDE_PROTECT_TEXT`** (and all it's relevant kernel components)
and run the simulator:
Now, there is no exception!

### Facts

1. Looking at Memory Browser I see the Changed Prologue Bytes (memory didn't change)!
2. Printing the buffer to console, prints the Replacement Prologue Bytes values! (Weird)
3. looking at assembly view (Mega Weird): shows the **Changed Prologue** Hex values but the Original Prologue asm commands (push bp;...) even though the byte value does not match them.

### My Questions

- Anyone had any experience with modifying `.text` segment?
- Anyone encountered memory that would not change (without an exception/signal) on simulator, which is not a memory mapped port/volatile ?

### Long Shot Assumption

I have an assumption it is about caching, hinting that vxWorks know this region shouldn't change, so it doesn't write_through, but don't know how i can check it...

**EDIT 2**: tried setting my pointers to be `volatile` => same behavior!

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about the question: but still have an answer.

1. there is an issue with the `Host_Tools` which does not show the changes to `.text` section.
   while on the target, the bytes actually changed.
2. the function didn't work because my transformation was ruining dynamic linking.

   - my function code, had a call to function with a constant string `"Whatever"`
   - when i transformed the function code, i unintentionally, changed the reference of a *relocation pointer* which at loading time got a bad absolute PTR.
     Lucky me, it pointed to a 0x00 buffer, and therefore printed an empty string without crashing.

### Suggested Solutions:

1. Do not touch the relocated Pointers both when altering the Executable and altering at Run-time.
2. Create a static self-contained executable with absolute footprint => no dynamic relocation occurs that way.
3. alter `dl()` to transform the altered reloacted pointers back to their expected relocated.
4. alter `dl()` to infer from the altered relocated pointers the expected altered absolute pointer, so the transformation will create absolute pointer.

**Note: I Choose #2 because it is the simplest, and because in my system, I do not need shared objects anyway.**

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer but since you are seeing expected output, it confirms that .text section is changed. Only explanation I can think of is if you are using host tools to look at the .text memory then there is a possibility that information may be read from host.

Did you typed commands on target to look at the memory location?

Comment: `d 0x<address> shows the correct, expected, **Replacement Prologue Bytes**